# Vue doesn't recognize my components, am I registering them wrong?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a basic blog app in Laravel using Vue.js. I've created custom components, registered them in my app.js file, and referred to them in the views by their component names. But I'm getting this error on load:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
>
> (found in )

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code:

CreatePost.vue:

```
<template>
<div class="card mt-4" :key="componentKey">
    <div class="card-header">New Post</div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div v-if="status_msg" :class="{ 'alert-success': status, 'alert-danger': !status }" class="alert" role="alert">
            {{ status_msg }}
        </div>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Title</label>
                <input v-model="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Post Title" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Post Content</label>
                <textarea v-model="post_body" class="form-control" id="post-content" rows="3" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class>
                <el-upload action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" list-type="picture-card" :on-preview="handlePictureCardPreview" :on-change="updateImageList" :auto-upload="false">
                    <i class="el-icon-plus"></i>
                </el-upload>
                <el-dialog :visible.sync="dialogVisible">
                    <img width="100%" :src="dialogImageUrl" alt />
                </el-dialog>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="button" @click="createPost" class="btn btn-success">{{ isCreatingPost ? "Posting..." : "Create Post" }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
.avatar-uploader .el-upload {
    border: 1px dashed #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.avatar-uploader .el-upload:hover {
    border-color: #409eff;
}
.avatar-uploader-icon {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #8c939d;
    width: 178px;
    height: 178px;
    line-height: 178px;
    text-align: center;
}

.avatar {
    width: 178px;
    height: 178px;
    display: block;
}
</style>

<script>
import { setTimeout } from "timers";
import { mapState, mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
    name: "create-post",
    props: ["posts"],
    data() {
        return {
            dialogImageUrl: "",
            dialogVisible: false,
            imageList: [],
            status_msg: "",
            status: "",
            isCreatingPost: false,
            title: "",
            post_body: "",
            componentKey: 0
        };
    },
    computed: {},
    mounted() {},
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(["getAllPosts"]),
        updateImageList(file) {
            this.imageList.push(file.raw);
        },
        handlePictureCardPreview(file) {
            this.dialogImageUrl = file.url;
            this.imageList.push(file);
            this.dialogVisible = true;
        },
        createPost(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!this.validateForm()) {
                return false;
            }
            
            const that = this;
            this.isCreatingPost = true;
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("title", this.title);
            formData.append("post_body", this.post_body);
            
            $.each(this.imageList, function(key, image) {
                formData.append(`images[${key}]`, image);
            });
            
            api.post("/post/create_post", formData, { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }})
            .then(res => {
                this.title = this.post_body = "";
                this.status = true;
                this.showNotification("Post Successfully Created");
                this.isCreatingPost = false;
                this.imageList = [];

                /* "that", defined above, used here instead of "this" to avoid conflict issues */
                that.getAllPosts();
                that.componentKey += 1;
            });
        },
        validateForm() {
            if (!this.title) {
                this.status = false;
                this.showNotification("Post title cannot be empty");
                
                return false;
            }
            if (!this.post_body) {
                this.status = false;
                this.showNotification("Post body cannot be empty");
        
                return false;
            }
        
            return true;
        },
        showNotification(message) {
            this.status_msg = message;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.status_msg = "";
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

app.js:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import store from './store/index';
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';

Vue.use(ElementUI);

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('all-posts', require('./components/AllPosts.vue').default);
Vue.component('create-post', require('./components/CreatePost.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    store,
    el: '#app',
});
```

posts.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <create-post />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <all-post />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: `all-post` != `all-posts`

Comment: Good catch, but this doesn't seem to be my problem. I've corrected all-post to be all-posts, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: can I see your layouts/app.blade.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Your component must be wrapped in an element with the id "app".

```
<div id="app">
  <all-posts />
</div>
```

make sure that somewhere in your posts.blade or layouts.app you have this element surrounding the code that includes your component

Comment: It doesn't appear that this is the answer. It looks like all of the content in layouts.app is already wrapped in a div with the id "app" and adding such a div directly into the blades still results in the same error message.

Comment: are you including the app.js script inside of the head tags of your layouts.app properly? for example in my project inside my head tags i use <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script> where "js" is the directory where my app.js file is located and the "defer" attribute tells the browser that it should go on working with the page, and load the script in background, then run the script when it loads.

Comment: '<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>" is already included at the head of layouts.app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the components and let your Vue instance know that there are custom components. In CreatePost.vue:

```js
import { elUpload, elDialog } from '...'; // path to your components or lib
...
export default {
...
  components: {
    elUpload,
    elDialog,
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear in the description, but CreatePost.vue *is* the component that isn't working. I've registered it in app.js and referred to the new element in home.blade.php, but I'm getting an error message telling me it isn't being recognized. There's another component similar to CreatePost that was set up similarly and also isn't working.